# How to hide server info when sending PHP mail?

Tags: php

I have something like this:

```
$to = '...';
$subject = '...';
$msg = '...';
$from = 'From: "me<me@domain.com.com>"';

mail($to, $subject, $msg, $from);
```

When I send emails, the "from" field always has Me  @my.serverinfo.com

How do I get rid of the server info?

*SOLVED* Got rid of the extra quote marks. Thanks @Daniel (and others)! I will read more about email headers. Also, I don't want to send anonymous email: me@domain.com was just to simply the example.

Comment: My dear because it is showing you email address. you have set from as your email address.

Comment: Why do you want to send anonymous emails?

Comment: There are perfectly good reasons for wanting to set the From header to something other than the default in php.ini. Particularly if you're using a shared host, the hostname in php.ini will have nothing to do with you or your website. Including a proper From is a matter of professionalism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does getting rid of the quotes help?

```
$from = "From: me<me@domain.com.com>\r\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

As Daniel mentioned, it's probably an issue with the quotations. As a side bit, if you have access to your PHP configuration, you can change it globally in [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

In Windows...

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.yourisp.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
sendmail_from = You@your.serverinfo.com
```

Or, if you're running Linux, see @OZ's answer for the directory.

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini find sendmail_path directive:

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -fyour@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably read a bit about the [e-mail RFC (2822)](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) and create your own string containing the headers you want to send. It's the first place where you should check out. There you can find if the header you want to send is in the official RFC and then write anything you want inside.